# How to write GraphQl Upsert Query in .graphql file

Tags: java, rest, graphql, hasura, manifold

I am able to execute upsert query in Hasura UI and I'm using manifold plugin for client classes generation in java. I'm struggling at keeping an on_conflict with multiple fields in .graphql file.
The below schema I'm using in graphql file. 

 Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

ex: 
schema:
`schema{
    mutation: MutationRoot
}`

MutationRoot

`type MutationRoot {
    insert_indv(objects: [insert_input!]!, on_conflict: input_on_conflict) : response!
}`

`input input_on_conflict{
    constraint: input_constraint!
    update_columns: [input_update_column!]!
}`

`input input_constraint{
    input_pk: Int
}`

`input input_update_column{
    studentMarks: Int
    studentRank: Int
    studentJoinDate: date
..................`

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is? Here is the upsert documentation https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/upsert.html

Comment: Thanks, @moto I got the solution.

Comment: Whoever gave me minus vote to ask me or tell me what you understand or what do you want to know about my post?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found an answer [graphql-rust/graphql-client](https://github.com/graphql-rust/graphql-client/tree/master/examples/hasura/examples), we need to use enums. I'm not aware that in graphQL schema file we can use enums.